# PHP, Function breaks when numbers are passed in as arguements

Tags: php

I have the following function which works well, if I call it with only the first parameter:

```
    function max_months($vehicle_age,$max_peroid,$no_older) {
            $tot_age_in = $vehicle_age + 315360000; 
            while ($tot_age_in > 536467742) {
                $tot_age_in = $tot_age_in - 31536000;
                if  ($tot_age_in < 536467742) {
                    $max_payback = floatval($tot_age_in - $vehicle_age);
                    $max_payback = seconds_to_month($max_payback);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return $max_payback;
        }
```

However, when I alter this function and pass in the numbers seen above as 
parameters, the function breaks.

```
function max_months($vehicle_age,$max_peroid,$no_older) {
                $tot_age_in = $vehicle_age + $max_peroid;   
                while ($tot_age_in > $no_older) {
                    $tot_age_in = $tot_age_in - $max_peroid;
                    if  ($tot_age_in < $no_older) {
                        $max_payback = floatval($tot_age_in - $vehicle_age);
                        $max_payback = seconds_to_month($max_payback);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return $max_payback;
            }
```

I'm calling the function like so:

```
$max_payback = max_months($vehicle_age,315360000,536467742);
```

`$vehicle_age` is set to 288897248

So in the first instance I return a valid number, however in the second instance I return false, even though the numbers are the same. Could anyone suggest why this might be? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It is highly likely that you run out of the `PHP_INT_MAX` value, you can check the maximum integer value by doing

```
echo PHP_INT_MAX;
```

If the variable is bigger than the `INT_MAX`, it is treated like a `float` value. This means, that you have to deal with floating point imprecision problems. And instead of checking <, == or >, you should check for a certain range *epsilon* around the value to be checked.

By changing your code like below, the problem is likely solved:

```
       function max_months($vehicle_age,$max_peroid,$no_older) {
            $e = 0.0001;
            $tot_age_in = $vehicle_age + $max_peroid;   
            while ($tot_age_in > $no_older-$e) {
                $tot_age_in = $tot_age_in - $max_peroid;
                if  ($tot_age_in < $no_older+$e) {
                    $max_payback = floatval($tot_age_in - $vehicle_age);
                    $max_payback = seconds_to_month($max_payback);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return $max_payback;
        }
```

See also: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

---

You did not have that problem when you used the hard coded numbers because they are treated like constants and therefore you did not have the float problem.

Comment: Thanks for that, unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the issue though having tried your code.

Comment: No, I just get the same issue - the return is false. I swear it works when those values are just set in the function as per my first code example. Very strange.

Comment: Could you do some debugging, `echo $tot_age_in` after setting it to see if it should enter the while loop.

Comment: Sure, I'm getting 604257437

Answer (score 1):

$max_payback is not always initialized. It's a good habit to always initialize the return value..

Comment: Yep, that is the reason why you get a False most likely, because the call does not even enter the while loop. Question remains why it does not enter the while loop, what is the value of `$vehicle_age` @Liam?

Comment: you could replace the break with return $max_payback